# Python: Run bash command with redirection in background and get the process id

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I am using `Python 2.6.6` from `Centos 6` platform.

I need to run a bash command from Python in background which contains redirection operators and need to read the background process's pid from the sub-process object.

I have tried the following code snippets, but it is not working.

**My Code**:

```
import subprocess

# Below code throws child_exception
myProcess = subprocess.Popen('tail -f -n 0 /home/user123/mainFile.txt >> /home/user123/tailFile.txt &', subprocess.PIPE)

#If I use the below command, terminating the process kills
#only the shell process and leaves the tail process as orphan
myProcess = subprocess.Popen('tail -f -n 0 /home/user123/mainFile.txt >> /home/user123/tailFile.txt', shell=True, subprocess.PIPE)

cmd = ['tail', '-f', '-n', '0', '/home/user123/mainFile.txt', '>>', '/home/user123/tailFile.txt', '&']
#Below line throws bash error saying: "cannot open file '>>'"
myProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

myProcessPid = myProcess.communicate()[0]
```

At the end I need to get the tail process's pid which is running in background.

Comment: `>>`, `&` are shell metacharacters; unless you use `shell=True` with `subprocess.Popen` it won't use the shell and those metachars would be interpreted literally...

Comment: I tried by using `shell=True` and tried giving it as both list and string. I am able to get the proper process id, but is is starting only the tail process without any arguments in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not useful or wise to wrap pure shell in python.

The `subprocess.Popen` object has ways of doing redirection and things like that by itself rather than by relying on a shell. Here's one example.

```
 import subprocess
 with open("ls.output.txt", "w") as f:
     # This is the way you'd run "ls -al > ls.output.txt" in the background
     p = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-al"], stdout=f) # This will run in the background

 p.wait() # Wait till process completes

 with open("ls.output.txt") as f:
        print (f.readline()) # Will print first line of ls -al output (total 2657828)
```

Comment: But I want to start bash command which contains redirection `> / >>` operators and terminate is gracefully

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want my tail output to be re-directed into another file

Comment: @Ashwin you're not reading what he said.  Open the file and use the *stdout* option to *subprocess.Popen()* to feed the data to it.  If you open the file in append mode, then output from the *Popen()* process will be appended to the file.  You can gracefully terminate *Popen.terminate()* method.  But you also don't need *tail* for any of this.

Comment: Thanks @NoufalIbrahim . I tried with with open () as filePtr: method instead of shell type redirection and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks @JimDennis

Answer (score 0):

These redirections won't be performed unless *shell=True* is passed to your *subprocess.Popen()* call.  The better way to do it is to use the *stdout=subprocess.PIPE* option and capture the output yourself.

The shell normally does the redirection for you. and this deal where you break the command up into a vector (list) of command and arguments is for the command as the shell would have passed those to an *execve()* system call.  The shell redirection, piping, and other operators aren't part of that.

Also you don't need the & operator as your *subprocess.Popen()* process is automatically running in the background.  It may be blocked on I/O, and you can poll and read that from the *suprocess.PIPE*.

More to the point you don't have to use a subprocess running the *tail* command at all.  If you just want to follow the end of the file you can do that using the *file.seek()*, *file.tell()*, *file.readline()* and the *os.fstat()* methods.

Here's a simple class which implements *tail -f* semantics directly in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import os, time

class Tail(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.fd = open(fn, 'r')  # file descriptor
        self.off = self.fd.seek(0, 2)  # end of file: skip the previous contents
        self.buff = list()
        self.last_line = 0
        self.sz = os.fstat(self.fd.fileno()).st_size

    def sleep(self):
        self.off = self.fd.tell()
        while self.sz - self.off == 0:
            self.sz = os.fstat(self.fd.fileno()).st_size
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def follow(self):
        while self.sz - self.off > 0:
            self.buff.append(self.fd.readline())
            self.off = self.fd.tell()
            self.sz = os.fstat(self.fd.fileno()).st_size

    def fetch(self):
        end = self.last_line
        self.last_line = len(self.buff)
        return '\n'.join(self.buff[end:])
```

... and here's some sample code using it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv[1:]) < 1:
        print('Must supply filename', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    fn = sys.argv[1]

    tail = Tail(fn)
    while True:
        print('... sleeping ...')
        tail.sleep()
        tail.follow()
        print(tail.fetch())
```

... which shows one way of using it.

I wouldn't use this class.  I'd change *Tail.sleep()* to *Tail.poll()* which would just immediately return a value indicating whether there's data ready at the end of the file. I'd also use the [Python Standard Library: select module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) for the polling and sleep. Then you could maintain a list of files that you're tailing all at once. Also the endlessly growing *Tail.buff* would be a problem; I'd either flush it automatically after each fetch or I'd add a method to flush it.

Comment: By the way I also wrote a simple snippet of code to do something similar using the Python mmap module: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-read-the-last-line-from-a-log-file-in-Python/answer/Jim-Dennis-1 ... that would have to be modified to return all new lines on each poll.